# What ${CC} means in makefile?

Tags: makefile, cc

I have makefile that uses `${CC}` variable for compiler selection:

```
${CC} $(CFLAGS) aaa.cpp -o aaa.o
```

During make ${CC} brings cc compiler. But there is no definition of `${CC}` in whole `makefile`. How this variable gets `cc`?

Comment: It, err, has a default value? Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Comment: I think you need to read a `make` manual page, or documentation about it in general. Do some research about *implicit variables*.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

Answer (score 6):

Some of the variables make uses in its implicit rules like `CC` have default values.

You can read more about them in the GNU make documentation about [variables used in implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html):

In general variables can also get their value through the environment or by passing command line arguments to make, as well as other ways for some special variables as documented [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Values.html#Values).